# Wicket: How to override onSubmit method from subclass?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a superclass A and subclass B. Superclass A has a form and onSubmit method. I would like to override that form method on a sublclass. How to achieve this?

Example A

```
form.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(form, "onsubmit") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            super.onSubmit(target);

            if (errorsList == null) errorsList = new ArrayList<>();
            prepareFormValuesForSubmit();
            PaymentsValidator.debtInfoIsValid(model.getObject(), errorsList);

            if (!errorsList.isEmpty()) {
                for (String error : errorsList)
                    error(error);

                JavascriptUtils.showMessagesForFeedbackPanel(target, feedback);
                return;
            }

            Long id = sendPayment(target);
            getOBSession().setAttribute((Object) DebtInfoViewPage.PAGE_PARAMETER, id);
            JavascriptUtils.goToPage(target, Constants.DEBTINFO_BASE_URL + "/" + DebtInfoViewPage.class.getSimpleName());

            getOBSession().setSaveDoc(false);
        }
```

On B:

```
getPaymentForm().add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(getPaymentForm(), "onSubmit") {

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
            PaymentsValidator.auditStatementIsValid(auditorsContactModel.getObject(), errors);
            if (errors.size() == 0) {
                auditorsContactModel.getObject().setDebtInfoId(getDebtInfoModel().getObject().getId());
                ServiceLocator.getService(DocumentService.class).persist(auditorsContactModel.getObject());
            }
        }
    });
```

That way is not working, seems like it is adding another onSubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `onSubmit(Form<?> form, AjaxRequestTarget target)` in A.java and delegate to it:

A.java:

```
 form.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(form, "onsubmit") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        super.onSubmit(target);
        /*A.this.*/onSubmit(form, target);
    }
});

protected void onSubmit(Form<?> form, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (errorsList == null) errorsList = new ArrayList<>();
        prepareFormValuesForSubmit();
        PaymentsValidator.debtInfoIsValid(model.getObject(), errorsList);

        if (!errorsList.isEmpty()) {
            for (String error : errorsList)
                error(error);

            JavascriptUtils.showMessagesForFeedbackPanel(target, feedback);
            return;
        }

        Long id = sendPayment(target);
        getOBSession().setAttribute((Object) DebtInfoViewPage.PAGE_PARAMETER, id);
        JavascriptUtils.goToPage(target, Constants.DEBTINFO_BASE_URL + "/" + DebtInfoViewPage.class.getSimpleName());

        getOBSession().setSaveDoc(false);
    }
```

B.java:

```
 @Override void onSubmit(Form<?> form, AjaxRequestTarget target) { {
   List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        PaymentsValidator.auditStatementIsValid(auditorsContactModel.getObject(), errors);
        if (errors.size() == 0) {
            auditorsContactModel.getObject().setDebtInfoId(getDebtInfoModel().getObject().getId());
            ServiceLocator.getService(DocumentService.class).persist(auditorsContactModel.getObject());
        }
 }
```